# Easier/functional way to turn each character of a string into its own object and display them with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

all,

I'm working on a language-learning app that compares Chinese characters to a "dictionary" array and displays whether or not the character is in that dictionary, along with its pronunciation in pinyin and its English meaning.
I'm having trouble getting the results to display **in order**.
Here's the bin: http://jsbin.com/julitiq/178/edit?html,css,js
`*`
What I want to do is:
I have a string called rawText, obtained from the ng-model of a textarea, and I want to go through it character by character.
Each character from rawText will be compared against the .chr attribute of each element in an array of objects ($scope.chrs).

*If there is a match*, I want to put the matching object from $scope.chrs into a second array of objects ($scope.infobox).
*If there isn't a match*, I want to make an empty object "template" (not a real template, just a dummy object), add the unmatched character to the empty object's .chr, and add this new object to $scope.infobox instead.

Finally, I want to display the contents of $scope.infobox **in order** using ng-repeat. Each div should contain the attributes of each individual object.
I'm no pro, so I'm sure there are better, more functional ways to do what I'm trying to do.

EDIT: I found out how to fix it using ng-change on the textarea to do the "objectifying", then running the object array using ng-repeat.

Comment: `var newentry = $scope.blank; newentry.chr = t; $scope.infobox.push(newentry);` ` $scope.blank` is an object. This code changes the very same object and pushes it into `$scope.infobox`. Therefore every time this line is executed, it will **update all entries of this object** in your Array, since they all reference the very same object.

Comment: I changed it to $scope.infobox.push({chr: t, pin: "", eng:""}); but it's still out of order.